# After security update MSCOMCTL.ocx can not be loaded

Tags: vba

A few days ago, some of users of my VBA application started to report to me, that macros are not working correctly. They got a message:

**"Could not load an object because it is not available on this machine."**

In my research I found out that problem is propably caused by security update:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2009/06/05/visual-basic-6-controls-stop-working-after-security-advisory-960715.aspx

http://dutchgemini.wordpress.com/2012/04/17/excel-vba-error-could-not-load-an-object-because-it-is-not-available-on-this-machine/

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2664258

I tried to apply suggested solutions. On some computers it was enough to just delete exd files and register the mscomctl.ocx.

On most of the computers, NOTHING helps. I really don't know what to do with them, there are dozens of users who just can't work!

Computers, on with problem occurs and won't go away are:

- Windows XP, Office 2003 with SP3
- KB2653956 update is the last one installed
- when I tried to install this: http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/security/bulletin/ms12-027 (first one listed) I get an error:

**"The expected version of the product was not found on your system"**

- deleting all the *.exd files and registering mscomctl.ocx does not help